# How do I prove that a graph if Hamiltonian it must be $2$-connected?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I understand that a graph is biconnected if each vertex has degree greater or equal to $2$.  Is it enough to say that a Hamiltonian Graph contains a cycle and every cycle has a least the degree of $2$?

Comment: That seems right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing things.

First, a biconnected graph is one where removing any vertex is not enough to disconnect it, or in other words, there are at least two disjoint paths between any pair of vertices. This implies that $\deg(v) \geq 2$, but it is not enough (e.g. take two triangles and connect them with one edge, you would have degrees 2 2 3 3 2 2, but the graph would not be biconnected, removing any of the vertices of the degree 3 would disconnect the graph).

Second, in "every cycle has a least the degree of 2" how do you define the degree of a cycle? Or perhaps you have meant "every vertex of every cycle has..."?

On the other hand, you have good intuition. The fact that the graph is Hamiltonian gives you a cycle that passes through all the vertices, and this implies that any two vertices are connected by at least two paths: going along the cycle clockwise and counterclockwise.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: while 2-connected is equivalent to "there are at least two disjoint paths between any pair of vertices" (actually, it is not for graphs with two vertices), this is not so straightforward that "in other words" is justified, I suppose.